# four way swich setup to control 2 outlets from 3 locations

Tags: electrical-distribution

[image: one with all 4 wires is first from panel][image: one with wire nuts is second and leads to first 3 way switch and works properly]I used an old book on running a four way switch circuit to run light from 3 locations, but in place of light I need two outlets.. book shows power to light first then to first switch. so I wired first outlet from panel then second outlet from it then to switch.  switches work properly on the second outlet but first one is always on

this is all new construction

novice here 
thanks for any help

Comment: How many conductors did you run between each box?

Comment: not sure on conductors?? wired outlets in series

Comment: Can you post photos of the boxes?

Comment: the one with wire nuts goes to first switch and works correctly with all three switches

Comment: I can't determine anything from those photographs. Imma guess.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you want to run power to the outlets first, but here's one way to do it:

[image: 2 outlet, 3 switch, power to load]

Note that modern electrical codes usually require a neutral wire be available in all switch boxes, against the possible future installation of smart switches.

White wires that are not neutrals, such as the travelers in this diagram, must be marked with paint or a bit of colored tape.

EDIT: For future reference, here is a good way to wire this installation with power brought to the furthest switch box first:

[image: 2 outlet, 3 switch, power to switch]

I would prefer this way because it requires less material between all the boxes.

Comment: You probably have omitted to bring the *switched* hot all the way back to the first outlet. You'll need a 10/3wg cable between the two outlet boxes, not a 10/2wg.

Comment: Personally (in my own house only) I am ignoring the requirement that neutrals be present in all switch boxes. I believe that in 10 or 12 years, homeowners will be asking on Home Improvement SE about all these superfluous capped-off neutrals everywhere, and the graybeards will be explaining about how we all once stupidly thought that smart switches were a good idea.

Comment: P.S. -- neutrals are also useful for high-performance dimmers for LED or fluorescent lights.

Comment: And for smart switches.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: Oh, I didn't know that about the dimmers. Okay, from now on I'll run neutrals to switch boxes. - I was just trying to protect my family from "Internet of Things" TCP/IP controllers.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri -- my take is that X-10 or Insteon are fine for "smart home" stuff, and even if you wanted TCP/IP, there is no need to put a Linux box in every blasted wall switch in your house...

Comment: A.I Breveleri   only reason i ran to outlets first  was the book i had...if there is a better way i can reroute everything still fairly easily...thank you i will try the hot back to first outlet

Comment: The only savings of the second method over the first is the reduction in material. If you've already run the wires, it may not make sense to re-do it unless you will re-use the removed material. - OTOH if you've run something like the first method, but without the neutrals in all the switch boxes, then the advantage of the second method is adding those neutrals while keeping the same 10/3wg between the boxes.